# how to maintain scroll state between posts in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

how to maintain the scroll state when Telerik grid Edit button is cliked.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to capture the current scroll position with javascript and then store it on a hidden field, then on your action create a javascript to return the user to the same position and print it in the view so that it gets executed, that's how webforms does it.